# alternative to maps

Tags: c++

Since maps dont allow duplicate values . Are there any other containers that are part of C++ standard library that allow duplicates that store values by key value pair?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [std::multimap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html)

> Multimap is a Sorted Associative Container that associates objects of type Key with objects of type Data. multimap is a Pair Associative Container, meaning that its value type is pair. It is also a Multiple Associative Container, meaning that there is no limit on the number of elements with the same key.

Comment: Can I get values in sorted order using a multimap?

Comment: Yes. Only std::unordered_map and std::unordered_multimap don't provide sorting.

Comment: By the way brett: `multimap` is usually in `<map>`, the interface is also the same. Just remember to use the `equal_range` member function when you search for something, otherwise you might forget some elements :)